# printing lists of unknown sizes side by side

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, dictionary

I have multiple sets of pairing lists stored in the dictionaries "dates" and "prices".
The lists are of unkown sizes, but I would like to print them side by side as in:

```
date_value1 price_value1 date_value2 price_value 2
```

At this moment, however I can only get it to print one after the other, as in:

```
for i in range(len(cities)):
    for j,k in zip(dates[i],prices[i]):
        print str(i) + " ; " +  j.text +" ; "+ k.text
```

I have tried to get it to do what I want by doing:

```
a = {}
for i in range(len(cities)):
    for j,k in zip(dates[i],prices[i]):
        print str(i) + " ; " +  j.text +" ; "+ k.text
        try:     a[i] = a[i-1] + " ; " + j.text +" ; "+ k.text
        except:  a[i] = " ; " + j.text +" ; "+ k.text

for i in a[len(cities)-1]:
    print a
```

But it does something else entirely different which I really couldnt figure out.

Can you help? Thanks.

---

This is how I fixed my code. Thank you F.J

```
a = 100000
for i in xrange(len(citynames)):
    if len(precos[i]) < a: a = len(precos[i])
    print citynames[i], " ; "," ; ",
print    

for j in xrange(a):
    for i in xrange(len(citynames)):      
        print datas[i][j].text, " ; " ,precos[i][j].text, " ; ", 
    print
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the key piece I think you are missing here, is how you can print without it automatically adding a line break, just add a `,` to the end, for example:

```
for i in range(len(cities)):
    for j,k in zip(dates[i],prices[i]):
        print str(i) + " ; " +  j.text +" ; "+ k.text,
    print
```

Every `print` statement inside of the inner `for` loop will append a space instead of a newline.  The `print` statement just after the inner for loop is to just print the line break so on the next iteration you start on a new line (not sure whether or not you want that).

However, a better alternative would be to look into using [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to construct the entire string you want to print.  For example:

```
for i in range(len(cities)):
    print ' '.join(str(i)+" ; "+j.text+" ; "+k.text for j, k in zip(dates[i], prices[i]))
```

Note that I have no idea if this is the exact format you want, but you should be able to adapt it to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer works but if I saw that in a code review I'd leave this answer as a comment:

Format the data, then present it.

Create a list of the rows, formatted in the way you want. Then print the rows. This approach is also easier to test, more readable and decoupled.

```
def append_to_rows(city, dates, prices, row):
  for date, price in zip(dates, prices):
    row.append(' ; '.join([city, date.text, price.text]))


def print_rows(rows):
  for row in rows:
    print row


def print_data(cities, prices, dates):
  rows = []
  for city in cities:
    append_to_rows(city, dates[city], prices[city], rows)
  print_rows(rows)
```

Test:

```
class Text(object):
  def __init__(self, text):
    self.text = text


cities = ['new york', 'san francisco', 'los angeles']
dates = {
  'new york': [
    Text('2008'),
    Text('2009'),
   ],
  'san francisco': [
    Text('2008'),
   ],
  'los angeles': [
    Text('2008'),
    Text('2009'),
    Text('2010'),
   ],
}
prices = {
  'new york': [
    Text('$500'),
    Text('$600'),
   ],
  'san francisco': [
    Text('$400'),
   ],
  'los angeles': [
    Text('$300'),
    Text('$400'),
    Text('$500'),
   ],
}

>>> print_data(cities, dates, prices)
new york ; 2008 ; $500
new york ; 2009 ; $600
san francisco ; 2008 ; $400
los angeles ; 2008 ; $300
los angeles ; 2009 ; $400
los angeles ; 2010 ; $500
```